# Count matching pairs (modular equality)

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm

### Problem

Given an array of natural numbers `a`. Find the number of such pairs of elements `(a_i, a_j)`, where `abs(a_i − a_j) mod 200 == 0` and `i < j`

### Solution

I came up with this solution:

```js
// n - the length of numbers array
// numbers - the array of natural numbers

function getNumberOfGoodPairs(n, numbers) {    
    let count = 0;
    const remainders = new Map();
    
    for (const num of numbers) {
        const remainder = num % 100;
        const modifiedNum = (num - remainder) / 100;
        
        if (remainders.has(remainder)) {
            const nums = remainders.get(remainder);
            
            for (const num of nums) {
                if (Math.abs(num - modifiedNum) % 2 === 0) ++count;
            }
            
            nums.push(modifiedNum);
        } else {
            remainders.set(remainder, [modifiedNum]);
        }
    }
    
    return count;
}
```

#### Notations

- `for (const arrayElement of array)` - get elements from the `array` one by one and put this element into `arrayElement`. It is same as:

  ```js
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    const arrayElement = array[i];
  }
  ```
- `new Map()` - is dictionary
- `%` - is `mod`
- `array.push(el)` - add `el` to the end of `array`
- `remainders.get(remainder)` - returns the array of numbers which remainder is equal to `remainder` when dividing by 100
- `remainders.set(remainder, [modifiedNum])` - add to dictionary new key `remainder` and value `[modifiedNum]`. `[modifiedNum]` - a dynamic array with one element `modifiedNum`

If I'm right the time complexity in worst case is O(n²).

Please help me to optimize this algorithm.

Comment: @greybeard I want to learn an algorithm regardless of a specific programming language

Comment: The way to speed up the procedure sketched would be to leave out what's mind boggling about it anyway. Review the idea of grouping inputs (modified or not) by remainder, and the need to compare the modulus of absolute differences. This isn't algorithm review. This is *code review*, I expect code to review to be working as is with a contemporary run-time environment.

Comment: it's a working javascript code, guys. I added the tag and removed the mention about pseudocode. Hopefully that makes the post ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a bit of algebra you can show that

```
(1)    abs(a_i − a_j) mod m == 0, m > 1
```

can be written as

```
(2)    (a_i − a_j) mod m == 0 if a_i >= a_j
(3)    (a_j − a_i) mod m == 0 if a_i <= a_j
```

on both cases it is the same as saying

```
(4)    (b − a) mod m == 0 if b >= a
```

Let's define the inverse of `mod m` as `invmod_m`

```
(5)    invmod_m(x mod m) = x
(6)    invmod_m(x) mod m = x
```

by applying the mod inverse we get infinitely many equations, but that' ok, we can deal with them all at once

```
(7)    invmod_m((b − a) mod m) == invmod_m(0)
```

from (5) we can simplify the left side

```
(8)    b - a == invmod_m(0)
```

now we can add `a` to both sides

```
(9)    b == a + invmod_m(0)
```

and do `mod m` of both sides again

```
(10)   b mod m == (a + invmod_m(0)) mod m
```

and distribute the `m` on right side

```
(11)   b mod m == a mod m + invmod_m(0) mod m
```

from (6) we see that `invmod_m(0) mod m` is zero so we have

```
(12)    (b mod m) == (a mod m)
```

And so you see, regardless of what the `m` is, two numbers are a good pair if and only if their remainder `mod m` is the same.

So an algorithm with `O(n)` time complexity is

- build histogram `R` of remainders `mod m`
- sum the number of good pairs (`R[r] * (R[r] - 1) / 2`) for each remainder `r` in `R` (with occurence `R[r] > 0`)

```js
type Solution = (numbers: number[], m: number) => number

const naiveSolution: Solution = (numbers, m) => {
    let count = 0
    for (let j = 1; j < numbers.length; ++j) {
    for (let i = 0; i < j; ++i) {
        const ai = numbers[i]
      const aj = numbers[j]
      if (Math.abs(ai - aj) % m === 0) {
        ++count
      }
    }
  }
  return count
}

const ezioSolution: Solution = (numbers, m) => {    
    let count = 0;
    const remainders = new Map();
    
    for (const num of numbers) {
        const remainder = num % 100;
        const modifiedNum = (num - remainder) / 100;
        
        if (remainders.has(remainder)) {
            const nums = remainders.get(remainder);
            
            for (const num of nums) {
                if (Math.abs(num - modifiedNum) % 2 === 0) ++count;
            }
            
            nums.push(modifiedNum);
        } else {
            remainders.set(remainder, [modifiedNum]);
        }
    }
    
    return count;
}

const slepicSolution: Solution = (numbers, m) => {
  const remainders = new Map/*<number, number>*/()
  for (let j = 0; j < numbers.length; ++j) {
    const aj = numbers[j]
    const r = aj % m
    remainders.set(r, remainders.has(r) ? remainders.get(r) + 1 : 1)
  }
  
  let total = 0
  remainders.forEach((count) => {
    total += count * (count - 1) / 2
  })
  return total
}


const solutionTestSuite = (name: string, solution: Solution): number => {
    let errors = 0

  const solutionTest = (expected:number, numbers: number[], m: number) => {
        const actual = solution(numbers, m)
    if (expected !== actual) {
        console.warn(`${name} returned ${actual} instead of ${expected}`, numbers, `(mod ${m})`)
      ++errors
    } else {
        console.info(`${name} returned ${actual} as expected`, numbers, `(mod ${m})`)
    }
  }
  
  console.info(`${name} starting`)
  
  const start = performance.now()
  solutionTest(0, [], 200)
  solutionTest(0, [0], 200)
  solutionTest(1, [0, 0], 200)
  solutionTest(1, [105, 505], 200)
  solutionTest(3, [205, 605, 5], 200)
  solutionTest(4, [205, 10, 605, 5, 1010], 200)
  const stop = performance.now()
  
  const time = `in ${stop - start} ms`
  
  if (errors > 0) {
    console.warn(`${name} gor ${errors} errors ${time}`)
  } else {
    console.info(`${name} OK ${time}`)
  }
  
  return errors
}

const testAll = () => {
    let errors = 0
  
    errors += solutionTestSuite('naive', naiveSolution)
  errors += solutionTestSuite('ezio', ezioSolution)
  errors += solutionTestSuite('slepic', slepicSolution)
  
  if (errors > 0) {
    console.warn(`${errors} errors in total`)
  } else {
    console.info(`ALL OK`)
  }
}

testAll()
```

Sorry for the typescript; I felt more confident doing it that way, but it should be fine to just remove the typings...

Comment: Thank you! Interesting solution. You can also check my answer with only one for loop :)

Comment: @EzioMercer Yeah,I realized i could do it directly without the next loop, but I had it already written and was lazy for refactor so I left that for you :) Anyway the idea is the very same.

Answer (score -2):

I [found a solution](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1516192/385375) with one for loop (rewrited in JS):

The time complexity is `O(n)`

Algorithm:

- We create an array with the size of 200 and fill it with zeros
- Instead of calculating the remainders dividing by 100 we calculate the remainders dividing by 200 - `remainder = num % 200`
- This `remainder` is the place in our prepared array where we will count the number of numbers with the same remainders
- Then we increase `count` by the value of `remainders[remainder]` and after this we increase the value of `remainders[remainder]` by 1
- When we reach out the end of `numbers` array we already have a total `count` of pairs

```js
function getNumberOfGoodPairs(n, numbers) {    
    let count = 0;
    const remainders = Array(200).fill(0);
  
    for (const num of numbers) {
        const remainder = num % 200;
        
        count += remainders[remainder];
        
        ++remainders[remainder];
    }
  
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Not really a good answer, good answers are supposed to make observations about the original code.

Comment: @pacmaninbw You are right! I will add this information ASAP